# virt-manager can't connect to libvirt: "Connection does not support required domain listing APIs"

Tags: libvirt, virt-manager

I can't connect with my local virt-manager (version 3.0.0) to the old remote libvirt setup (version 0.8.3):

```
Unable to connect to libvirt qemu+ssh://user@example.com/system.

Connection does not support required domain listing APIs

Verify that the 'libvirtd' daemon is running on the remote host.

Libvirt URI is: qemu+ssh://user@example.com/system

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/connection.py", line 1006, in _open_thread
    self._populate_initial_state()
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/connection.py", line 960, in _populate_initial_state
    raise RuntimeError("Connection does not support required "
RuntimeError: Connection does not support required domain listing APIs
```

The daemon *is* running on the server and the socket *is* available. Also the SSH connection is definitely succeeding as SSH multiplexing is in use.

Answer (score 1):

virt-manager version 3.0.0 does not support a that old libvirt version (0.8.3 in this case). virt-manager version 2.2.1 needs to be used instead, or a more current libvirt version