# Getting "can't connect to default" error on shutdown after installing virt-manager on Debian

Tags: linux, debian, virtual-machine, virt-manager

I am running Debian 12/Bookworm with KDE Plasma. Ever since I installed `virt-manager` I am getting the following message when rebooting. It sits here for 30+ seconds before it continues with the boot process.

Google is not showing anything helpful. How can I fix this so my system doesn't sit for 30 seconds when trying to shutdown/reboot?

> `libvirt-guests.sh[7306]: Can't connect to default. Skipping.`

Also, this is not the same as [virt-manager can't connect to libvirt: "Connection does not support required domain listing APIs"](https://superuser.com/questions/1590470/virt-manager-cant-connect-to-libvirt-connection-does-not-support-required-dom) because mine is talking about `default`, not `libvirt`.

Answer (score 1):

For me I needed to change settings in /usr/lib/libvirt/libvirt-guests.sh

```
ON_SHUTDOWN="ignore"
SHUTDOWN_TIMEOUT=1
```

[link](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/virtualization_deployment_and_administration_guide/sect-shutting_down_rebooting_and_force_shutdown_of_a_guest_virtual_machine-manipulating_the_libvirt_guests_configuration_settings)